# position absolute's form validator gives error but posts the form whatsoever

Tags: jquery, validation

i am using position absolute's form validator http://goo.gl/7wpza

i installed it correctly and it works, but there might be a bug or something. it gives errors when i click into an input box, but it posts the form whatsoever.
i mean, if i click on an input box which i declared in html as `required` and input nothing, red error box appears and complains that it should not left blank, some input is required as it should. but when i press submit button, without any entry, it sends the form, despite it has NOT been validated.

i posted to the author, but he might be busy or tired of answerind questions -i did not pay anything yet- there is no respond yet. 
have you ever confront something like that?
do you have any ideas about?

any help is appreciated..

```
<form method="POST"  action="addArticleMetaBody2Newdb.php" id="multiForm" >
<input class="input_box validate[required] text-input" name="Article_Doi" type="text" id="Article_Doi" ></input><br/>
<input class="input_box"  name="Volume" type="text" id="Volume" ></input><br/>
<input class="input_box validate[required,custom[integer]] text-input"  name="Issue"            type="text" id="Issue" ></input><br/>
<input class="input_box validate[required,custom[integer]] text-input"  name="fpage"            type="text" id="fpage" ></input><br/>
<input class="input_box validate[required,custom[integer]] text-input"  name="lpage"            type="text" id="lpage"></input><br/>
<input class="input_box validate[required]" type="textbox" name="tags" ></input><br/> 
<input class="input_box validate[required] text-input" type="textbox" name="categories" ></input><br/>
<input class="submit_button"    type="submit"  value="oluştur" id="submit" ></input>
```

a bit of code..

Comment: can you post some sample code because I have used this plugin before and never faced such an issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, your example is missing the ending form tag, and on lines 6 and 7 the tag name and the class attribute name are squished together.

Comment: hi Ann, it is just a copy-paste problem. actual code is fine with that..

Comment: The default action of `<input type="submit />` element is to submit. I do not believe the plug-in will prevent this action unless you specifically do so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your plugin is working as it should, try this in jQuery:

```
    function validate() {
        if ($('#form1').validationEngine('validate') === false) {
            $('#form1').validationEngine('validate');
            return false;
        }
```

In my project, this function was called by the `OnClientClick attribute` of the submit button, and then opened a dialog when true, and quits execution of any Javascript/jQuery or code-behind.

If yuse this solution, you must put a `return false` statement in the click like this:

```
OnClientClick="openDialogIfVisited(); return false;"
```